# Android Tab sometimes located along with Action Bar but sometimes below it, how to control?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, titanium, tabbar, android-tabs

I am using Titanium to build my Android app, which use TabGroup and have two tabs.

When run on simulator (Genymotion with virtual device: Samsung Galaxy Note 3 ), the two tabs show in a tabBar which occupy the full screen width right below the ActionBar. So there are 2 bars at the top of the screen.

But if test on real device (I am using LG G Pad), the tabBar somehow merge with the actionBar, two tabs are shown inside the actionBar, next to the app icon. And there is only one bar at the top of the screen. This is what I actually want.

Is there anyway to control where the tabs appear?

I am testing with Ti SDK 3.2.3.GA and API level 19

Thanks.